# Is it possible to insert an image as an excel commentary by means of PHPExcel/PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpexcel-1.8.0

Is it possible to insert an image as an excel commentary by means of PHPExcel/PhpSpreadsheet?

The way of adding simple text comment is this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('A1')->getText()->createTextRun("comment example");
```

[this in an example how it should look like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aBYU.png)

Comment: So, What does it mean? :) If you have question, you can ask!;)

Comment: The question is how to add an image as an excel comment via PHPExcel/PhpSpreadsheet.
like this
https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-lp18/excel-comments-manager-lp18/add-picture-comment.png